# Cannot Install FormCalc on Linux

Tags: feyncalc

[image]

so i tried to install FormCalc on linux and when i run the compile command i get "cannot determine mathematica's system ID using_/usr/local/bin/math"

Has anyone encountered such error and is there a way to fix it ?

Comment: Could you please run: math -run 'Print[$SystemID]; Exit[]' , and show the result?

Comment: Does the file `/usr/local/bin/math` exist and is it executable?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered same error. Just notice 3 points :-
1. Check the file/folder permissions of FormCalc. Using ls -la in terminal. 
2. Is form is installed or not? Form is required to run FormCalc using Mathematica.
3. Try to run $SystemID command in mathematica. For sure output comes like Linux_ something. It is fine. Otherwise install Mathematica again.